# How to get the current padding of a Google Map (Android API)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, padding

How can I get the current padding of a Google Map provided by the Google Maps Android API?

I know that I can set the padding with `setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)`.

But I want to change only the left padding and keep the others.

Comment: There is no such method in map. You can yourself store the values that you are using for padding.
https://github.com/itsdebs/MapEasy/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vagabond/mapeasy/maphandler/MapManagerImpl.java

Here I have implemented few map methods, you can check out. I am also working on other functionalities of map.

Comment: thank you for this hint!

Answer (score 0):

seems like you cant do this yet. could be intentional. use a decorator pattern and wrap around the googlemap object and store the padding yourself so you can retrieve it.